# Javascript inside Django Template

Tags: javascript, arrays, django, django-templates, javascript-objects

I am using JS inside Django template, but the JS code isn't responding. What to do?

This inside `<script>` tag:

```
 var pageStrucVal = {{ pagestruc }};
        if (pageStrucVal >= 82){
            var pageWarn = ["Brilliant, your site's structure and design is awesome and rocking. <gold>RockingStructure</gold>", 'pp']
        }
            
        else if ( pageStrucVal >= 72){
            var pageWarn = ["Nice, your site's structure and design is suitable", 'pp']
            }
            
        else if ( pageStrucVal < 45){
            pageWarn = ["Extremely bad condition, your site's structure and design is extremely bad and unmanaged. Strictly to use a different theme or change the interface (UI). <red>#ExtremelyBad</red>", 'dd'];
            }
        else if ( pageStrucVal < 50){
            pageWarn = ["Worst conditon, the content quality of your site is too much poor. Use a well-managed theme or change the interface (UI).<orange>#ReallyPoor</orange>", 'dd'];
            }
        
        else if ( pageStrucVal < 55){
            pageWarn = ["Too much bad, your site's structure and design is too much bad and unmanaged. Try to use a different theme or change the interface (UI).<orange>#VeryPoor", 'dd'];
            }
        
        else if ( pageStrucVal < 63){
            pageWarn = ["Very bad, your site's structure and design is very unmanaged. You can try to use a different theme or change the interface (UI).<orange>#MuchBad</orange>", 'dd'];
            }
        
        else if ( pageStrucVal < 72){
            pageWarn = ["Bad, your site's structure and design isn't suitable. Small change in the interface (UI) is required.<green> #TendsToBad</green>", 'dd'];
            }
        console.log(pageWarn);
        document.getElementById(pageWarn[1]).appendChild(document.createElement('p')).innerHTML = (pageWarn[0]);
```

Is `document.getElementById(pageWarn[1]).appendChild(document.createElement('p')).innerHTML = (pageWarn[0]);` correctly written and in correct position?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class='plusNdefects' id='moredetails'>
            <h1>Good Aspects and Plus Points.</h1>
            <p class='details'>Here are some awesome good aspects and benefits you have in your site to get Google Adsense.</p>
        
            <!-- Ads ::> -->
            {% include "ads/outads.html" %}
            <!-- Ads <:: -->
        
            <div class='persona'>
                <div id='pp'> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class='plusNdefects'>
            <h1>Disabilities and Improvements.</h1>
            <p class='details'>These are some disabilities of your website that are stopping you from being approved by Google
                Adsense.</p>
        
            <!-- Ads ::> -->
            {% include "ads/outads.html" %}
            <!-- Ads <:: -->
        
            <div class='persona'>
                <div id='dd'></div>
            </div>
```

'pp' and 'dd' are the id (location) where I wanna insert the messages. 'pp' stands for pluspoint and 'dd' stands for defects.

Comment: What do you mean not responding? Can you please elaborate what you are trying to do?

Comment: It isn't giving any result. The last element of array `pageWarn[1]` is the id of `div` tag and I wanna insert the message inside that `div` tag which has index 0 i.e. `pageWarn[0]`.

Comment: Can you please, post your complete html?

Comment: Have a look, please. I've posted it now.

Comment: Your html and javascript looks good. What `{{ pagestruc }}` is returning? Did you try replacing `{{ pagestruc }}` with any other integer value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think user qoutes outside the django tag is a better idea.`var pageStrucVal = parseInt('{{ pagestruc }}');`

Answer (score 1):

try `var pageStrucVal = parseInt({{ pagestruc }})`;

Comment: It worked according to your idea. `var pageStrucVal = parseInt({{ pagestruc }});` is the correct answer.

Comment: Do that mean checking the green tick button. Sorry for being a noob. If 'yes' I've already done it.

Comment: One more favour from you. Can you help me to decrease the length of the code?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't see where it can be simplified. You can use javaScript minifier or some other tool to minify it though.